# How to share same Thunderbird profile between two users?

Tags: thunderbird, email, share, user-profile

I have been using **Thunderbird** e-mail client with my default account in my desktop Ubuntu (Lucid Lynx).

Now, I have created another user. When I start Thunderbird when logged in this new account, I would like it to use exactly the same profile than the default user.

Let's suppose the user/group names are **default** and **newbie** (*/home/default* and */home/newbie* being their home folders).

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider simply running Thunderbird as the same user, regardless of which of the two users is the one who is logged in. This would be suitable if the two users have absolute trust for each other (or, more narrowly, if the user whose Thunderbird profile it is has absolute trust for the other user, since it's the user whose Thunderbird profile it is who would have to give the other user his or her password).

If you want to do it that way, then one user can run Thunderbird as the other user with the command:

`gksu -u other-username thunderbird`

Where `other-username` is replaced by the other user's username.

This command can be run in the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), or from the Run Application menu (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>), or a launcher icon or menu item can be created to run this command.

So `default` could run Thunderbird as `newbie` with:

`gksu -u newbie thunderbird`

And `newbie` could run Thunderbird as `default` with:

`gksu -u default thunderbird`

The password for the user whose username is `other-username` is required, to run Thunderbird like that.

---

Alternatively, if you want to actually set things up so that both users are using the same Thunderbird profile, then you can make one user's `~/.mozilla/thunderbird` folder (where `~` represents the user's home directory) a symbolic link to the other user's corresponding folder. In order for this to work, that profile must be accessible by both users, so a group should be created for this, both users added to the group, and full read and write permissions given to the folder for all users in the group.

For example, if the user `newbie` wants to make make his Thunderbird profile the same as the user `default`'s profile, and `default` is an administrator, and `default` is OK with this, then with Thunderbird not running, `default` could run:

`sudo addgroup default-thunderbird`
`sudo usermod -a -G default-thunderbird default`
`sudo usermod -a -G default-thunderbird newbie`
`cp -R ~/.mozilla/thunderbird ~/.mozilla/thunderbird.backup`
`chgrp -R default-thunderbird ~/.mozilla/thunderbird`
`chmod g+rw ~/.mozilla/thunderbird`
`find ~/.mozilla/thunderbird -type d -exec chmod g+x \{\} \;`

And then, with Thunderbird not running, `newbie` could run:

`mv ~/.mozilla/thunderbird ~/.mozilla/thunderbird.old`
`ln -s ~default/.mozilla/thunderbird ~/.mozilla/thunderbird`

Please make sure to back up any important Thunderbird data before doing this, and be very careful, because:

(1) I have not tested this to see if it works, or how well!

(2) This is quite a bizarre way to set things up, which the Thunderbird developers probably did not have in mind. Thus, this might trigger bugs and/or strange Thunderbird behavior.

---

Finally, have you considered, instead of any of the complex solutions detailed above, simply having both users be separately set up to use the same (or some of the same) email accounts in their respective separate Thunderbird configurations?

If these are IMAP accounts (rather than POP), then emails are stored on the server all the time anyway, and then there is really no reason to try to have two user accounts using Thunderbird with the same profile.

Comment: cool idea better and correcter and too long. maybe some easy couse what if later dont need that option? i would be just using symlink

Comment: @Kangarooo Are you suggesting making `~newbie/.mozilla/thunderbird` a symlink to `~default/.mozilla/thunderbird` without running the other commands above? Because if so, that will not work--`newbie` does not have the necessary permissions to create the link, and even if the link is made by `default` (using `sudo`), `newbie` will not have permissions write profile data, and quite possibly won't have permissions to read profile data either.

Comment: @EliahKagan: Great! Thanks! When asking, I thought about the symlink, but I was afraid of the problems you mentioned in the comment above (and resolved in your answer). But I will try the `gksu` approach first... so simple!

Comment: No im suggesting to use symlink method with permissions of course.